# What would the type of the following be?

Tags: haskell, types

Im just starting learn Haskell new, I'm struggling with determining the type for the following:

```
    1) one x = [x]
    2) three x = (x,x,x)
    3) first x y = x
    4) mult m n = m*n
    5) [(False,’0’),(True,’1’)]
```

Comment: Why ask us when you can just ask GHCi with the `:t` (or `:type` ) command?

Comment: how would i use that in the terminal?

Comment: sounds like you really haven't been taught the very basics. Have you read Chapter 1 of Learn You a Haskell? http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out [You'll have to go back a little to the introduction if you haven't downloaded GHC yet.] Incidentally, the entire book is an excellent introduction to Haskell (it's what I started with, fwiw).

Comment: as a followup to my last comment, I just realised that types, and the `:t` command, aren't covered until the following chapter ("Types and Typeclasses")

Comment: I see, thank you very much, Im just starting to learn so this'll be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `one x = [x]` is a that takes an element and returns a list with that element only, so it has type `one :: a -> [a]`
2. `three x = (x,x,x)` has trivial type `three :: a -> (a,a,a)`
3. `first x y = x` looks like the Prelude function `const` that has type `first :: a -> b -> a`
4. `mult m n = m*n` has the same type as `(*)`, which is `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`
5. `[(False,’0’),(True,’1’)]` is not even a function, so has simple type `:: [(Bool, Char)]`

Remember you can always use they GHCi function `:t` to return the type of an expression

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, especially the part about answering well-asked questions.

Comment: @chepner are you saying I shouldn't have answered because it's asking for multiple questions?

Comment: Yes, the linked FAQ is pretty explicit: "Avoid trying to answer questions which ... request answers to multiple questions."

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I'm new to the site so I thought they counted as one questions as its basically all the same topic

Comment: Such questions are usually homework dumps: why else would they be asking about the types of a list of random expressions with no context?